# Magento admin blank screen after installing Mailchimp module

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

I've been playing with this module from Mailchimp/Mandrill: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ebizmarts-magemonkey-official-mailchimp-and-mandrill-integration.html

I had no problem locally, but when I tried installing it in production the admin interface stopped working! Actually, there were no error instead, only a blank (and disappointing) screen.

Before getting mad, read what I've done (as answer to this question):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncomment the following line at `index.php`:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

This will give some idea of the problem. If you're facing the same problem I was, you'll need to edit the following file `app\code\community\Ebizmarts\MageMonkey\Model\Feed\Updates.php` around line 114:

```
        if (count($feedData)) {
            $inbox = Mage::getModel('adminnotification/inbox');
            if ($inbox){
                $inbox->parse($feedData);
            }
        }
```

If you're not really interested in keeping the module installed, you can simply uninstall the module via command line:

```
./mage uninstall community Ebizmarts_MageMonkey
```

By adding the internal if clause, the error stopped bothering me. Please, comment **if you have a better solution**.

+1 is always welcome :D